# Android Bitmap Contrast Implementation

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, contrast

I want to create an app which applies contrast to an image and then displaying that image in ImageView. I found [this](http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/07/bw-contrast-and-color-contrast-image-in.html) example code and it doesn't seem to work properly. After applying the contrast it just makes everything greeny. Here is what I have in my program:

```
public class ImageImprovementActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button buttonLoad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_improvement);

        buttonLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoad);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(getImage());

        buttonLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(applyContrast(((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap(), 0.3));
            }
        });
    }

    private Bitmap getImage() {
        final File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testImage2.jpg" );

        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            return bmp;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private Bitmap applyContrast(Bitmap image, double contrastVal) {
        final int width = image.getWidth();
        final int height = image.getHeight();
        final Bitmap contrastedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, image.getConfig());

        int A, R, G, B;
        int pixel;

        double contrast = Math.pow((100 + contrastVal) / 100, 2);


        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                pixel = image.getPixel(x, y);
                A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                R = Color.red(pixel);
                R = (int)(((((R / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
                R = truncate(R);

                G = Color.green(pixel);
                G = (int)(((((G / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
                G = truncate(R);

                B = Color.blue(pixel);
                B = (int)(((((B / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
                B = truncate(B);

                Log.i("ImageImprove", A + " " + R + " " + " " + G + " " + B);

                contrastedImage.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
            }
        }
        return contrastedImage;
    }

    private int truncate(int value) {
        if (value < 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (value > 255) {
            return 255;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea what the problem could be? Also if you have another example, please post it, it could be useful.

**Edit**
Also it seems that the result every time is the same, no matter what value I give for `contrastVal` in `applyContrast(Bitmap image, double contrastVal)`

**Edit2**
I'm sorry, actually there is a visible difference when changing `contrastVal`. Still the image is greeny..

**Edit3**
I'm adding some images so you can get more clear what the problem is.

Here is the original image:

[image]

And here is after applying contrast with contrastVal 1:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little error in your code (copy error?). Change

```
G = truncate(R);
```

To

```
G = truncate(G);
```

Comment: Oh, code.. I don't know how could I miss that. Thank you. It really worked!